# Fast way to apply the function for a number to pandas.series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The problem is described for the specific case here, but it would be valuable for lots of similar project.

One pandas.series called *month* contain the month date of each sample in the format of **int** (1,2,3,4,...).  I want to change it into the style of "01, 02, 03, ... 12" and then add it with year.

Using **"{0:0=2d}".format(a)** and **loop**, the series values can be transformed easily:

```
df['date'] = np.nan
for i in range(0,len(df),1):
    df.date.iloc[i] = df.year.iloc[i] +"-"+'%2d'%df.month.values.iloc[i]   
### df.date is a new series contain the year-month('2017-01','2017-02')
```

But loop strategy is un-efficiency, is there any simple way to achieve the same target?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `apply`:

```
month.apply("{0:0=2d}".format)
```

## Timing

- Psidom's method

%timeit month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)

*10 loops, best of 3: 39.1 ms per loop*

- This method:

%timeit month.apply("{0:0=2d}".format)

*100 loops, best of 3: 7.93 ms per loop*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':pd.np.random.randint(1,12,10000),'year':pd.np.random.choice([i for i in range(2004,2017)],10000)})

df.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.month.apply("{0:0=2d}".format)
```

Output:

```
0       2014-10
1       2012-04
2       2015-03
3       2014-05
4       2007-03
5       2008-04
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert *month* to `str` type and then use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
month = pd.Series([1,2,12])

month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)

#0    01
#1    02
#2    12
#dtype: object
```

To concatenate it with year:

```
df.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` on a dataframe with appropriately named columns, to create a series of datetime objects.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(year=[2011, 2012], month=[3, 4]))
df

   month  year
0      3  2011
1      4  2012
```

All we're missing is the `day` column.  If we add it, we can pass it to `pd.to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1))

0   2011-03-01
1   2012-04-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Well, that was convenient.  Now what?

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)).apply('{:%Y-%m}'.format)

0    2011-03
1    2012-04
dtype: object
```

Or

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

0    2011-03
1    2012-04
dtype: object
```

---

Make a new column

```
df.assign(year_month=pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))

   month  year year_month
0      3  2011    2011-03
1      4  2012    2012-04
```

---

However, we could have just done

```
df.assign(year_month=df.apply(lambda x: '{year}-{month:02d}'.format(**x), 1))

   month  year year_month
0      3  2011    2011-03
1      4  2012    2012-04
```

Comment: And in terms of efficiency; string methods may outperform this at the construction phase but the things you'll do afterwards will probably be much faster and easier with datetimes.